# how use where query in firebase data base android java

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to Update the All Students of class where classection=Six:B Which Query I can use please Guide there Are many students I want to update All the student of six class at the same time.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to Update the All Students of class where classection=Six:B

To achieve that, you need to use a Query to filter the students based on the "classection" property. To also perform an update, for example, to change the value from "Six:B" to "Six:C", please see use the following lines of code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference studentsRef = rootRef.child("Students");
Query classSectionQuery = studentsRef.orderByChild("classection").equalTo("Six:B");
classSectionQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                ds.child("classection").getRef().setValue("Six:C");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result of this code will be the update of all students "WHERE" classection is equal to "Six:B".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67595588/how-to-solve-this-error-did-not-receive-expected-priority-boost please guide me